# Which one is faster? List.contains() or Map.containsKey()

Tags: java, list, collections, dictionary

I'm writing an algorithm where I look for pairs of values which when added together results in another value I'm looking for.

I figured out that using a `Map` will speed up my algorithm from O(n²). I later realized that I don't really use the values contained in my `Map` so a `List` will suffice.

I did a power search on Google but I did not find any information on the asymptotic running time of those methods in the title of my question.

Can you point out where should I look for such information?

Comment: A fairer comparison would be `Set.contians()` vs `Map.containsKey()`, which is basically equal - for every type of Map there's a corresponding Set type used in its impl

Comment: I know I know, but I think that It would be a several hour project to perform an asymptotic analysis on the JCF code.

Comment: Sounds like you want to put the values into a list and iterate from both ends irregularly trying to match the sum. Still O(n). For more complex pairs, a Bloom filter may be appropriate.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

> I later realized that I don't really use the values contained in my `Map` so a `List` will suffice.

`Map` isn't just a list of key-value pairs, it is a unique mapping from keys to values. So when you change from `Map` to `List`, you are allowing duplicates where you previously didn't. On the other hand, a `Set` is exactly a `Map` without the values. So consider using a `HashSet`.

As for the search complexities:

`list.contains` is O(n), `hashSet.contains` is O(1), and `treeSet.contains` is O(log n).

For general information on now `HashMap` works, google for "hashtable". For `TreeMap`, google for "binary tree" or similar. Wikipedia has good entries on these subjects.

Be careful, however, to avoid the class `Hashtable`. It's an archaeological artefact in the modern library. For your case `HashSet` is probably the best choice.

Answer (score 7):

`Map`and `List` are interfaces, so there is no information on their implementation nor their performance. But if you use the most current implementations (`LinkedList` or `ArrayList` for `List`, and `HashMap` for `Map`), the `contains()` method must, in the worst case, go through the entire list, and compare your element with each entry. It is an O(n) operation.

If you use an `HashMap`, the implementation is radically different : the `HashMap` contains an array with more entries than elements in it (in practice, you have an array size of between 4n/3 an 3n/2 for n elements in the map). It computes the hash of the key, which is an int, and wrap it between 0 and your array size (let's say this number is `i`). Then it will put the element at the index `i` of the array (or `i+1`, `i+2`… if previous indexes are already taken). So, when you check for the key presence with `containsKey`, it will re-compute the hash and the `i` value, and check the `i`, `i+1`… indexes until it finds an empty array cell. Theorically, you can have an O(n) worst-case, if the array is almost full, are all the keys have almost identicals `i` values, but with a good hash function, you have constant-time `contains` and `get` functions. (However, adding elements is fast if you don't need to resize the array, which is **REALLY** slow - I think you need to recompute the indexes of each key).

So a map is really faster if you need to check the key appearance in a collection, and do not need to keep the order (there is a `SortedHashMap` for that, but I don't know it's performance), but it will take more memory.

Also, if you don't need the key-value thing, you can use a `HashSet` (which is internally the same as an `HashMap`).

Comment: That's because I wanted to know all of the implementations' speeds.

Answer (score 2):

HashSet seems to be faster:

- HashMap: 267
- ArrayList: 2183
- HashSet: 57

Also note that .contains() normally does not need to be called on HashMap and HashSet, but I kept it on the code to more accurately answer your question:

```
    long t = System.currentTimeMillis();
    HashMap<String, Boolean> map = new HashMap<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
        String s = (Math.random() * 100) + "";
        if (!map.containsKey(s)) {
            map.put(s, true);
        }
    }
    System.out.println("HashMap: " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - t));

    t = System.currentTimeMillis();
    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
        String s = (Math.random() * 100) + "";
        if (!list.contains(s)) {
            list.add(s);
        }
    }
    System.out.println("ArrayList: " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - t));

    t = System.currentTimeMillis();
    HashSet<String> set = new HashSet<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
        String s = (Math.random() * 100) + "";
        if (!set.contains(s)) {
            set.add(s);
        }
    }
    System.out.println("HashSet: " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - t));
```

Answer (score 0):

Map.containsKey() considering that you are using a HashMap since searching in HashMap is done in O(1).

List.contains() generally should resort to sequential search or a binary search thus the complexity will be atleast O(log n)