# Quick way to search through arrayList

Tags: java, arraylist, contains

I have an arraylist `Arraylist<String[]>` and I am trying to find a quick way of looking for a specific value on a specific index of the `String[]`. My `ArrayList` is always going to contain `String[]` of length 2. And what I want to do is look through the `ArrayList` for any `String[]` that has a specific value i.e. `str[1]="value"`. I know that I can iterate through the `ArrayList` taking every single element (`String[]`) and then looking for the value using `str[1].equals("value")` but I was wondering if there is a quicker way of doing it by maybe using `contains()` of the `ArrayList` or something.
thanks

PS: I don't know the value of the first element of my array (`str[0]`) so I cannot construct a new `String[]` and check if the `ArrayList` contains that

Comment: Try rethinking your data structure to improve the operations you are trying to do on the same

Comment: Well if your `String[]` are only of length `2` and you are putting them into an `ArrayList` why not just change all of that into one `Map<Key,Value>`? I think this would solve your problem

Comment: I think I should probably do that @3kings. But even using this approach how would I do that? Both `ArrayList` and `Map` have a way to see if there are specific elements inside but how would I combine them without having to iterate through the `ArrayList`?

Comment: and BTW the reason why I am using a `String[]` instead of a `HashMap<String, String>` s because I wanted a biderectional structure. On a `Map` I cannot get the key using the value

Comment: @Rakim Then why not make the `value` the `key`?

Comment: @3kings for the same reason as above :p I want biderectional access to both!

Comment: @Rakim Yeah but you know what the key is because you are getting the value from the `Map`. Let the key be `value` and just call `map.get("value");` now you have the value also

Comment: this will help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11613382/which-one-is-faster-list-contains-or-map-containskey

Answer (score 1):

## LinkedHashMap

How about using a `LinkedHashMap<String, String[]>` instead of the `ArrayList`? The key would be the `String[1]` value. `Linked` because that gives you predictable iteration order.

## An auxiliary Map

Or you could create a `Map<String, Integer>` where the key is the `String[1]` value and the value is the index of your `String[]` in the `ArrayList`.

```
ArrayList<String[]> al = new ArrayList<>();
Map<String, Integer> alIndexMap = new HashMap<>();
// ...
Integer nextIndex = al.size();
al.add(someStringArray);
alIndexMap.put(someStringArray[1], nextIndex);
```

If you keep `al` and `alIndexMap` in sync all the time, you'll always know where in `al` is the array that you're looking for.

## Guava BiMap

Google's *Guava* has some classes that implement their `BiMap` interface. It's like a `Map`, but it works both ways, i.e. you can use the `value` as a `key` if you want.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have checked the `BiMap` but as it is for a Uni project I am aiming to use the minimum amount of dependencies so not really want to use Guava. As for the above solutions I am still trying to work my head around what exactly you have in mind. Not really with you :p

Answer (score 1):

If you look into ArrrayList#contains - you will see, that this method also iterates through all elements.

You could use a parallelStream - so that the ArrayList can be searched by more threads.

```
    List<String[]> listToSearchIn = new ArrayList<String[]>();

    List<String[]> matches = listToSearchIn.parallelStream()
            .filter((element) -> element[1].equals("value"))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: sorry again. My title is probably misleading. By "quick" i meant "less coding" not "less iterations". Maybe I should reformat my title

Comment: Well, if you can use Java 8 then this is just the above one-liner. (You can use a normal stream() as well)

Answer (score 0):

Unless your ArrayList is sorted then O(n) efficiency is the best you can do. Unless by "quick way" you mean a method which does the iteration for you. Even in this scenario the answer is no since you're wanting to check data inside the String[] objects themselves.

Comment: yes I meant quicker as in sorter in terms of code. but as you said.. still!